# How can we make SSO with Hosted-Name Site Collections with different sub-domains?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

How can we make SSO with Hosted-Name Site Collections with different sub-domains for ADFS

authentication

like the following :

1st : http://siteA.Site.com

2st : http://siteB.Site.com

thanks

Comment: Once you configure your ADFS as Trusted Identity Provider you'll achieve SSO because the ADFS will 'know' the user on the second request and automatically return a valid token.

Comment: can you please guide me how can I do this ? thanks alot for your support

Comment: There are plenty guides to follow on this. For example: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305235(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I tried to go through with this article but I faced many problems with the steps , thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used cookies between the two sub-domains for SSO as the following :

1-user visit http://siteA.Site.com and logged into the system

2-a cookie is created with site.com as its domain

3-the cookie contains data about the user authentication which is encrypted

4-when the user try to visit the 2nd site : http://siteB.Site.com , if the cookie is
existed then the authentication data is extracted from the cookie and populating user's 
session with this data